# How to remove a required attribute from a HTML form (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I am making a "bestelpagina" also known as an order page. I made my own error, if something wasn't right with the input. HTML 5 already has a sort of error like this, but I prefer my own one. My own one doesn't work, because the other one already does the job. I don't know how to remove the required attribute. This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE = "html">
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block content %}
      <h1>Bestelpagina</h1>
      <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.firstname.label }}<br>
            {{ form.firstname(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.firstname.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}

        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.lastname.label }}
          {{ form.lastname(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.street.label }}
          {{ form.street(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.housenumber.label }}
          {{ form.housenumber(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.postcode.label }}
          {{ form.postcode(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.livingarea.label }}
          {{ form.livingarea(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.country.label }}
          {{ form.country(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.phonenumber.label }}
          {{ form.phonenumber(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.email.label }}
          {{ form.email(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.housenumber.label }}
          {{ form.housenumber(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ form.delivery.label }}
          {{ form.delivery(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
      </form>
      {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```